# Compilation error in Vivado

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I downloaded Vivado free Web Pack and try to simulate the simple project like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity async_RS_trig is
    Port ( R : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
       nQ : out  STD_LOGIC);
end async_RS_trig;
architecture async_RS_trig of async_RS_trig is
    signal bQ,nbQ : std_logic;
begin
    bQ <= R nor nbQ;
    nbQ<= S nor bQ;
    Q   <= bQ;
    nQ  <=  nbQ;
end async_RS_trig;
```

When I push Run simulation Vivado try to compile this code and I receve the error:

```
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3409] Failed to compile generated C file       xsim.dir/async_RS_trig_behav/obj/xsim_0.c.
```

But code is right, I tried to simulate an empty architecture and receved same error. What have I do to fix it?

Thank you!
Regards

Comment: I've searched and only found one reference to this error, no definitive answer, where there might have been an issue with the installation of Vivado on a Windows platform. If you find an answer please answer this your self so it's recorded here.

Comment: Is this a simulation only error or has synthesis also a problem with this code? Maybe the error is outside of this module e.g. in it's instantiation. You can also try to add a delay to `bQ <= R nor nbQ` like this `bQ <= transport R nor nbQ after 1 ns;`. The only way to find a solution for this kind of errors is to play with your code, comment and uncomment lines or modules and maybe try different toolchains like synthesis, questa sim, ghdl, ... Last question: Do you use the newest Vivado edition 2014.2?

Comment: Yes, I tried to reinstall Vivado. Yes I use Vivado 2014.2. Synthesis go without errors. I had another inexplicable errors when I tried to use Xilinx ISE on Windows 8, but ISE was unsupported on Windows 8.1.I try to change the code, try the empty design, when I do syntax error I receive messages about it. My last variant is about Windows 8.1, but I try to do something else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved.** This are few steps which you have to check:

1. I don't know about drive, but directory name don't have commas in it name and may be another bad :) symbols. The best folder to install is C:\xilinx :)
2. Full uninstall Comodo internet security, because switch off didn't help and made some another troubles.
3. I read about including Xilinx, Xilinx license and Projects folders to antivirus exceptions, but I didn't made this

I hope it will help to someone :)

Comment: Oh the installation folder problem ... I'm using ISE since 9.1 and there were always problems with folder and file names which are not compliant to the DOS 8.3 naming scheme. As of ISE 14.7 most tools are fixed, but some have still issues with whitespace in names. Sometimes there are also issues with hard coded folder names... so C:\Xilinx is the best solution. This is also true for Altera, QuestaSim, ModelSim and co.

Comment: Yes, I heard about folder problem in ISE, but I thought Vivado doesn't have such problem :)

Comment: The problem is always when you have space in your directory name, this problem was solved in previous version of Vivado, but it popped up again with 2014.4. The problem is with your %USERPROFILE% parameter contains space or any "unacceptable" characters. Check out the http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/62444.html

Comment: Thank you. You are right about spaces, but I had problems without spaces too. In addition to directory name I had problems with Comodo. May be they fixed this now...

Answer (score 0):

Please rename to your architecture to 'rtl' or what ever, but don't use the entity's name as architecture name again.

**Reply to Comment 1:**

The simulation uses 2 processes, in case of iSim these are:

1. *YourTestbench*_isim_beh.exe
2. Simulator GUI (isimgui.exe)

Your source files get translated into C source files, which are than compiled and linked to an executable file. You can run this *.exe file in interactive, (tcl)batch or gui mode. If you call this *.exe with -gui the simulator GUI gets launched and connects to the *YourTestbench*_isim_beh.exe via TCP (TCP based interprocess communication - IPC).

Normally your personal firewall should ask to grant isimgui.exe permission to connect at any port on localhost.

As you are using Vivado and xSim, you should grant this connection permissions to Vivado's GUI process.

This problem will occur also for the hardware server (hw_server).

Comment: No it is not a solution. Problem was in Comodo software and antivirus software. I turned it off. Simulation go more far, but I receive a new error :) FATAL_ERROR: PrivateChannel: Error connecting to server socket
ERROR: [Simtcl 6-50] Simulation engine failed to start: Simulation exited with status code 4.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 13.1 Design units, para 5 "Each primary unit in a given library shall have a simple name that is unique within the given library, and each architecture body associated with a given entity declaration shall have a simple name that is unique within the set of names of the architecture bodies associated with that entity declaration." 3.3.1 General, para 3, "The identifier defines the simple name of the architecture body; this simple name distinguishes architecture bodies associated with the same entity declaration."  Architecture simple names are in a different name space.